# nativescript-youtubeplayer toggle fullscreen in nativescript-vue app

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to do a fullscreen in youtube player from the plugin `triniwiz/nativescript-youtubeplayer` in my `nativescript-vue` application on android device but I'm unable to achieve so.

I have following code:

```
<template>
    <Page actionBarHidden="true" class="page" >
        <GridLayout orientation="vertical" width="100%" height="100%" columns="*" rows="*,auto">
            <StackLayout col="0" row="0" backgroundColor="#f8f8f8">
                <StackLayout backgroundColor="#44557f">
                    <Label :text="name" class="font-weight-bold"
                           color="#FFFFFF" padding="15" fontSize="20" textWrap="true"></Label>
                </StackLayout>

                <ScrollView orientation="vertical" height="100%">

                    <ScrollView orientation="vertical">
                        <StackLayout class="home-panel">
                            <YoutubePlayer ref="player" :src="videoLink.substring(17)" apiKey="**********" isFullScreen="true"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </ScrollView>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['videoLink','name','id'],
        mounted() {
            let player = this.$refs.player
            player.toggleFullscreen();
        }

    }
</script>
```

But I'm getting an error stating

> toggleFullscreen() not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access an element via Ref, the return value will be a Vue element. You should access the `nativeView` to gain access to the actual element.

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['videoLink','name','id'],
        mounted() {
            let player = this.$refs.player.nativeView;
            player.toggleFullscreen();
        }

    }
</script>
```